# Container for keeping butter/chocolate at 74°F/66°F (23°C/19°C)?

Tags: chocolate, butter, refrigerator

Keeping my entire home at 74°F isn’t practical. Is there a device for storing butter and chocolate at a temperature that’s reasonable for use and consumption? Two devices, one to warm in the winter and cool in the summer?

I’m looking for something with a thermostat that maintains temperature fairly precisely for under $200.

Answer (score 2):

One option might be using either a mini-fridge or wine cooler, and the addition of an external temperature controller, which overrides the internal temperature setting. Combined, the cost would be at or under your $200 target. Here's an example of [Johnson Controls Digital Thermostat Control Unit (on Amazon)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00368D6JA)

[image]

Comment: An excellent suggestion! For heating, I imagine I could put in a heating pad. :-)

Comment: @danorton: I don't know that you'd need a heating pad, were you to keep the inside temp at 75 degrees year round, right?

Comment: How would the container/refrigerator reach 75F if the room temperature is 68F?

Comment: @danorton; because it's regulating it inside of the frig, overriding the internal mechanism.

Comment: We don't seem to be understanding one another. There needs to be something in there too heat it, otherwise, from 65F to 74F. Basic physics.